# QGIS navigates to some other coordinate locations...Facing problem while dealing with coordinate systems

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

In QGIS 3.32, I want to do Geo-referencing of a vector shapefile.

The project coordinate system is Projected Coordinate System WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N EPSG 32643.

Two layers (Google Satellite Hybrid AND ShapeFile) both have same coordinate system as project that is UTM 43 N EPSG 32643.

Now I have coordinate lets say 24°03'42.01"N, 73°34'08.01"E of one place in India and covert it to UTM 43 then values come as 2661795.2114185407 N, 354499.71264807903 E.

But when I enter these values (longitude 2661795.2114185407, latitude 354499.71264807903) in Lat Lon Tool/Plugin in QGIS then it points me to an area in Cango nation of Africa.

[image]
Also I see that in status bar, QGIS shows some other values like 2773825.17991955, 8195517.73715534 for that place of India.

Please guide me how to deal with this issue and properly navigate to 24°03'42.01"N, 73°34'08.01"E

Regards

Answer (score 0):

2661795.2114185407 is the latitude (y coordinate, northing).

354499.71264807903 is the longitude (x coordinate, easting).

As of your explanation, you mixed them up

Comment: I am not getting. Please see when I use UTM 43N coordinate system, I mention above and locate a place in India, it gives coordinate information in status bar 2751594.17092387, 8192375.64752007 while when I check the same place coordinates in Google earth it shows entirely different values either in decimal format or equal degree format